# Size of Fields in bytes per table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, size, byte, ssms

I've been asked to work out:
"Total size of fields in bytes per table (for one record). Don’t include NVARCHAR(Max) fields, instead provide number of VARCHAR(max) fields, for that table."

not the greatest description, but it's what I've got to work on.

Basically, is there a way to find the size of each field for a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  o.name TABLE_name, c.name colimn_name, c.max_length, t.name type
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id=o.object_id AND o.type='U'
JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id=t.system_type_id
```

length -1 indicates max

Edited to include data type

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to inspect the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and/or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Do not know if the sizes are written in bytes, but this could help you!

Comment: I've tried that already, but thanks, it's the closest thing to what I want so far!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. I don't know of a built-in way, and I couldn't find one.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE DATA_TYPE
           WHEN 'numeric' THEN (CASE WHEN NUMERIC_PRECISION <= 9 THEN 5
                                     WHEN NUMERIC_PRECISION <= 19 THEN 9
                                     WHEN NUMERIC_PRECISION <= 28 THEN 13
                                     ELSE 17 END)
           WHEN 'int' THEN 4
           WHEN 'bigint' THEN 8
           ... --whatever other datatypes you want to handle, like tinyint, datetime, etc.
           ELSE 0 END)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
```

I've gotten those numbers via the documentation. I'm pretty sure every type lists the size in bytes, so you should at least be able to do this if you can't find anything better. At least there aren't many types in SQL...

I know the spec told you to disregard `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but if you wanted you could even give another column that shows the maximum size of the row, or even just the offset *to* said maximum, by using the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column.